# what query should I use in my google sheet to select data

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have data in the following format. 
I want to select how many `event_type` "Battles" in 2018. I have tried this query `=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C3122;"select A, count(B) group by A")`
but the results were not what I expected

this is the sheet.

[image: Google sheet data]

What query should I use in my Google sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C10,"Select Count(A) Where  A = 2018 AND B='Battles' label count(A) 'Total Event - Battles'")
```

Change Label text and data range per your requirement

[image]